# Need to create modules using admin panel instead of running commands

Tags: laravel-backpack

WE are building a laravel application with crud operations , as per the backpack documentation i understood how to create a module using the command
php artisan make:migration:schema create_tags_table --model=0 --schema="name:string:unique,slug:string:unique"
php artisan migrate

## STEP 2. create crud

php artisan backpack:crud tag
 is there any way that i can create a new module with required columns through admin panel itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know, Backpack for Laravel doesn't have a way to create cruds from the panel itself. but you can call commands from your own controllers.

for example:

```php
Artisan::call('backpack:crud tag');
```

take a look at the documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands